# Image doesn't render when width and height are defined in percentage with <table> parent element

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm trying to scale down an image by percentage and this renders correctly in Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer.  The img tag needs to be inside a table.

```
<TABLE>
 <TR>
  <TD>
   <img src="test.gif" width="60%" height="60%">
  </TD>
 </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Is there a better way to do this so it works in both browsers?

Comment: Sorry, neither answer seems to be correct.
I specify the height/width in pixels as workaround, but suppose IE has a bug that percent cannot work.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the dimensions in CSS instead:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .myImg{
        width:60%;
        height:60%;
    }
</style>

<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <img src="test.gif" class="myImg" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I don't think some browsers like when you define width/height inline as anything but a numeric value (i.e., `width="200"`);

Anyway, give that a shot - good luck

Comment: ...or even in-line style tag i.e. ...src="test.gif" style="height: 60%; width: 60%;" />

Answer (score 0):

Check out the source on http://www.joelonsoftware.com/ - the images within articles scale quite nicely. Use FireBug to help you with figuring out the CSS that will accomplish the scaling you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  table.full-width-table{
    width:100%;
  }
  td.center-text-td{
    text-align: center;
  }
  img.sixty-percent{
    width:60%;
    height:60%;
    margin:0 auto;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="full-width-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="center-text-td">
      <img src="test.gif" class="sixty-percent"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```